# Como sumar minutos a una hora con Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, carbon

Estoy usando Carbon para manipular las fechas en mi plataforma, y no tengo ni idea de como resolver esto.

```
public function theTurnIs($tipe){
    $fecha_actual = $this->getTodayDate('notFormat');
    $parse_date = Carbon::parse($fecha_actual);

    $hora = $parse_date->hour;

    if ($tipe == "hospital") {
        if($hora > 19 || $hora < 7){
            return "morning";
        }elseif ($hora > 13 || $hora < 18) {
            return "late";
        }
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que necesito comparar horas y media, pero `Carbon::parse` solo me devuelve o la hora, o el minuto... y lo que necesito es comparar algo

```
if($hora > '19:30' || $hora < '07:30'){
   return "morning";
}
```

y que la variable `$hora` tenga una hora con minutos... para poder compararlas...
¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en este caso lo único que necesitarías seria usar la función `format` que tiene carbon, de la siguiente manera:

`$hora = $parse_date->format('H:i');`

De esta manera lo transformas a hora y minutos, y esta disponible para hacer la comparación.